# C# and Tasks - UI Thread Hang - Pre-Async/Await keywords

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying to understand what the correct code to grab a set of data asynchronously when I do not have access to the client lib I am using to retrieve the data. I specify an endpoint and a date range and I'm supposed to retrieve a list of playlists. What I have now never comes back after the Start() call. Note: this is running in a WinForm. I am trying to better understand Tasks and don't just want to jump to awaits or a BackgroundWorker. I know I'm getting lost somewhere.

```
    private void GoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string baseUrl = "http://someserver/api";
        var startDateTime = this._startDateTimePicker.Value;
        var endDateTime = this._endDateTimePicker.Value;
        _getPlaylistsFunc = delegate()
            {
                var client = new PlaylistExportClient(baseUrl);
                return client.GetPlaylistsByDateRange(startDateTime, endDateTime).ToList();
            };
        var task = new Task<List<Playlist>>(_getPlaylistsFunc);
        task.ContinueWith((t) => DisplayPlaylists(t.Result));
        task.Start();
    }

    private void DisplayPlaylists(List<Playlist> playlists)
    {
        _queueDataGridView.DataSource = playlists;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I made these changes but now the application seems to hang the UI thread.

```
    private void GoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string baseUrl = "http://someserver/api";
        var startDateTime = this._startDateTimePicker.Value;
        var endDateTime = this._endDateTimePicker.Value;
        var token = Task.Factory.CancellationToken;

        var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var client = new PlaylistExportClient(baseUrl);
                _queueDataGridView.DataSource = client.GetPlaylistsByDateRange(startDateTime, endDateTime).ToList();

            },token,TaskCreationOptions.None,context);

    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `GetPlaylistsByDateRange` do you see that it actually gets called?

Comment: You'll need to pass a sync context to the continuation so that it runs in the UI thread instead of another thread pool thread.  Other than that, I don't see any real errors here.

Comment: Your update runs *all* tasks on the UI thread.  Only the second one should run there.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern. It's quite straightforward:

```
private async void GoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string baseUrl = "http://someserver/api";
    var startDateTime = this._startDateTimePicker.Value;
    var endDateTime = this._endDateTimePicker.Value;
    var playlists = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var client = new PlaylistExportClient(baseUrl);
        return client.GetPlaylistsByDateRange(startDateTime, endDateTime).ToList();
    });
    _queueDataGridView.DataSource = playlists;
}
```

Note that this will block a threadpool thread; if you can modify the library to have a `GetPlaylistsByDateRangeAsync` method, you can make this more efficient.

**Edit:** If you're stuck on .NET 4.0, you can install [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) to get full `async`/`await` capabilities. If - for some inexplicable reason - you *still* can't use `async`/`await`, then you can do it like this:

```
private void GoButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string baseUrl = "http://someserver/api";
    var startDateTime = this._startDateTimePicker.Value;
    var endDateTime = this._endDateTimePicker.Value;
    var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var client = new PlaylistExportClient(baseUrl);
        return client.GetPlaylistsByDateRange(startDateTime, endDateTime).ToList();
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        _queueDataGridView.DataSource = t.Result;
    }, context);
}
```

However, note that your error handling is more complex with this approach.

Comment: I was defineately trying to learn how this is done pre-async/awaits. But also good info to have.

Comment: I gave this answer based on the `async-await` tag specified on the question. If you want a pre-`async` answer, either `Task.ContinueWith` (coupled with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`) or `BackgroundWorker` would suffice. `async` code is much cleaner than either of those options.

Comment: See updated answer for code using the `ContinueWith` approach.

Comment: +1. The updated code is exactly what the poster wanted, except `Task.Run` needs to be `Task.Factory.StartNew`. `Run` did not exist in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Yeaah, there is no [`Task.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382.aspx) in .NET 4.0 and it still is not available even after installing [VS2010 Async CTP (Version 3)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983). If someone stuck with .NET 4.0 then he is usually stuck with VS2010 for which your reference to [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)  is useless

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of developers stuck with .NET 4.0 but very few who are stuck with VS2010. The Async CTP and `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` both provide the `Run` method on the `TaskEx` type instead of `Task`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're assigning to a property of a UI control in a background thread. That's usually bad news. WPF usually throws an exception when you do that, not sure about WinForms.

Capture the data in the background thread, but switch back to the main UI thread before assigning it to a UI control. Try posting the data to the UI thread using something like

```
    var uiSync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var client = new PlaylistExportClient(baseUrl);
            var list = client.GetPlaylistsByDateRange(...).ToList();
            uiSync.Post(() => _queueDataGridView.DataSource = list, null);
        },token,TaskCreationOptions.None,context);
```

Comment: Hmm. I understand - I think. .Post() is not a method on my context though.

Comment: Woops. Ok, what you're calling a context variable is actually a scheduler. I"ll update my answer with code to grab the synchronization context.

Comment: Looks like that is really close. Thanks. I'm just working out the Post() lambda argument. Right now the IDE is reporting back improper signature on the anonymous function.

Comment: Still locking up my WinForm. Only change I made was adding in (object state) to the Post() call.